# What is a good practical application example of the Dynamic Language Runtime in .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net-4.0, c#-4.0, dynamic-language-runtime, vb.net-2010

I wish to better understand the *real-world* application of this new feature that consists the [`Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.aspx).

I would like:

1. Brief explanation of how it could be used;
2. A brief sample code that shows how to take advantage of it.

Thanks! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dynamic Language Runtime is used as a platform to create [dynamic languages.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language)

Comment: Does it have nothing to do with Dynamic Types? I thought the two were coming together in the .NET 4.0?

Comment: Have a look at the Wikipedia article I linked.  If you are referring to the `dynamic` keyword in C#, that's just a way to statically type a variable that has runtime type semantics.

Comment: I might have read the Wikipedia article, I don't get how to take advantage of it in a real-world application, plus, I don't get all the concepts, excepts that it seems to be for implementing new dynamic languages or so. Perhaps a language barrier, I couldn't say.